# How can I import .json files in nodejs using ECMA Modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, module, require

I am using nodejs 14.6.0. In my package.json file, I have type set to module.

```
type: module
```

Upon trying to do the following:

```
import serviceAccount from 'serviceAccount.json'
```

I get the following error: `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for C:\Users\Aditya\youtube-discord-bot\database\serviceAccount.json`

Now, online it says that I must change my start script like so: `node --experimental-json-modules index.js`. However, even after having this, the same error occurs.

Is there a workaround to this? I want to require the serviceAccountKey using this functionality, as when trying to export it (as a .js file), Firebase gives me an error.

In the past, before doing this, I have simply been using `require('./serviceAccount.json')`, and this has worked fine. However, I want to switch to use these new ECMA modules.

Answer (score 6):

in case you need to use a .json file that you cannot alter and convert to an export, you can still use require as follows:

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use webpack: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#json
2. transfer the json file to a js object:
   **config.js**

```
    export default
    {
      // my json here...
    }
```

then...

```
    import config from '../config.js'
```

Comment: thank you. Where you wrote 'my json here...', do I put the actual json, or rather a javascript object?

Comment: great answer, maybe webpack is the only way, because node support es6 module in limited way, not so good support.